# nav2d stage to gridmap transformation

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, nav2d, stage-ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm using nav2d in ros kinetic.
The configuration is the one of `tutorial3.launch`.

During the navigation I printed the start and goal coordinates used by the exploration algorithm (NearestFrontierPlanner).
However I am not able to establish the relation between these values and the real robot position (provided by stage).

My goal would be to understand this relation in order to send navigation goals to the robot. From the stage coordinates I could obtain the gridmap ones and finally the cell index to send as goal to the navigator.

This is what I tried:

```
int compute_goal(GridMap* map, unsigned_int &goal, float stage_x, float stage_y)
{
    double resolution = map->getResolution();

    auto grid_x = stage_x / resolution;
    auto grid_y = stage_y / resolution;

    unsigned int index;
    map->getIndex(grid_x, grid_y, index);

    goal = index;
    return EXPL_TARGET_SET;
}
```

The outcome is wrong. The navigator always says that the point is not reachable.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/302745/nav2d-stage-to-gridmap-transformation/) by [alsora](https://answers.ros.org/users/30341/alsora/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1322 on 2018-09-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found the solution in the Nav2d code itself.

The navigator sends the goal to Rviz through a marker using the following transformation.

```
marker.pose.position.x = mCurrentMap.getOriginX() + (((double)goal_x+0.5) * mCurrentMap.getResolution());
marker.pose.position.y = mCurrentMap.getOriginY() + (((double)goal_y+0.5) * mCurrentMap.getResolution());
```

I only had to apply its inverse.

---

Originally posted by [alsora](https://answers.ros.org/users/30341/alsora/) with karma: 1322 on 2018-09-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0